# European passport return service - copying other passport pages

Tags: united-kingdom, eu, family

My wife will be applying online for permanent residence as an EEA national, and we are including me (non-EEA national) in her application, so we can use the European passport return service.

The application wants me to include my previous Family Permit (expired) and Residence Card (still valid) as supporting documents. For me, those documents are part of my passport.

Will the EPRS be able to copy and certify these pages as well? They are part of my passport, so I hope yes. But I'm concerned they will say they can only copy the bio data page, which forces me to submit my passport anyway, or leaves me unable to submit the originals of those supporting documents.

Unfortunately the council agent isn't able to answer questions in advance, and by the time I have the appointment I must already have declared in the application whether I can submit those documents.

Does anyone have any experience with getting the EPRS to copy 3 pages of a passport, instead of one?

Comment: I do not know the answer, but I suspect that this text bodes ill for your plan: "The European passport return service can only be used to verify and copy your and your family’s passports, to submit with your applications. National identity cards and other supporting evidence must be submitted as originals only." (Source: [European passport return service](https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/european-passport-return-service))

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps anyone else down the line, the EPRS confirmation says they copy "all relevant pages" of your passport.  It turns out, at least in my council office, that means the EPRS service copies your entire passport.  So the pages containing my family permit and old residence card (along with every other visa and travel stamp) were included in their certified copy.